# Replace a string in multiple files using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to find and replace a string in multiple files using bash command. I am using `sed` which I am not really familiar with.

My variables:

```
$FILE = (/home/user/file1.txt, /home/user/file2.txt)
$REL = 5.0
```

My code:

```
for f in ${FILES[@]}; do sed -i "$f" "s/__ver__ =*/__ver__=$REL/g";
```

output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `/'
```

What is wrong with my expression?

Comment: could be there multiple occurrences of `__ver__ =` within a file?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No, only one.

Comment: You attempt to assign `FILE` (but fail because the `$` should not be there) but then you attempt to use `FILES`.  Actually, you should also not use uppercase for your private variables.  In fact, I see no good reason to put the file names in a variable in the first place.  Similarly, you want `REL=5.0` with no dollar sign and no spaces around the equals signs.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ catches these and many other common beginner errors.

Answer (score 0):

1) The *filename* should be specified as the last argument for ***sed*** expression:

2) bash's `for` loop should ended with `done` keyword

```
for f in ${FILES[@]}; do sed -i "s/__ver__ =*/__ver__=$REL/" "$f"; done
```

---

If your files have similar naming format you can avoid `for` loop:

```
sed -i 's/__ver__ =*/__ver__=$REL/' /home/user/file[2].txt
```

Comment: ... or `sed -i 's/from/to/' "${FILES[@]}"` if the OP is really insistent on having the files in a variable.

Comment: It's likely that `=*` should actually be `= *`.